# Why doesn't the session timeout value work?

Tags: asp.net, session

The security model on our application works something like this, (very simple I know):

```
public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session[EnumsAndConstants.Keys.UserId] == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically on every page that is 'Protected' we have the code:

```
private void VLSProtectedPage_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
    }
```

In our web config we have the line:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=xx;User Id=xx;Password=xx;" timeout="1" />
```

However the timeout of 1 minute is not working. If I leave the page idle for more than 1 minute I am still logged in.

Whats very strange too is the results that I get back from the session database:

SessionId   Created Expires LockDate    LockDateLocal   LockCookie  Timeout Locked
ha4b05pqsnopfwu2wqiohkce2b7731d2    2011-08-17 14:24:07.303 2011-08-17 14:25:17.867 2011-08-17 14:24:17.840 2011-08-17 15:24:17.840 14  1   0

You can see that the created dattime is '2011-08-17 14:24:07.303' however I only logged onto the application at 15:25. So it looks like the .net session engine is 1 hour premature. I have checked the system datetime and this is correct.

All in all even through the exprires time is an hour early this should mean my app times out instantly but it doesnt, it doesnt time out at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your Web.config on the web server in sync with the one in your dev environment? Maybe the site is currently still using an older version without the 1 minute timeout setting?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Express?

Comment: I am using Sql Server Express...

Comment: When you say are the web.config in sync? Well the web configs are slightly different but surely .net just adds an entry that relates to web.config of the application being browsed?

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you set the sessionState InProc?

Comment: Hi Johnny5 I can confirm that I dont get the same behaviour when I change to inProc. So I get the expected behaviour, any ideas?